# Groupby and expand on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Name    Num    ID
Red      1     ABC
Red      1     DEF
Red      1     GHI
Blu      2     JKL
Blu      2     MNO
Blu      2     PQR
Blu      2     ZYP
```

I am trying to perform a `groupby()` on `Num`, and then expand the dataframe so that it looks like so:

```
ToName    ToNum    ToID    FromName    FromNum    FromID
  Red       1       ABC      Red          1         DEF
  Red       1       ABC      Red          1         GHI
  Red       1       GHI      Red          1         DEF
  Blu       2       JKL      Blu          2         MNO
  Blu       2       JKL      Blu          2         PQR
  Blu       2       JKL      Blu          2         ZYP
  Blu       2       MNO      Blu          2         PQR
  Blu       2       MNO      Blu          2         ZYP
  Blu       2       PQR      Blu          2         ZYP
```

Really all it does is groupby  Name/Num, and then find every combination of ID associated with the group. The hard part where I get lost is how to expand the dataframe on the combinations of `ID`

Answer (score 1):

`merge` first then apply `sort` then `drop_duplicates`

```
s=df.merge(df,on=['Name','Num']).query('ID_x!=ID_y')

s[['ID_x','ID_y']]=np.sort(s[['ID_x','ID_y']].values,1)

s=s.drop_duplicates()
```

```
    Out[61]: 
       Name   Num  ID_x  ID_y
    1   Red    1    ABC  DEF
    2   Red    1    ABC  GHI
    5   Red    1    DEF  GHI
    10  Blu    2    JKL  MNO
    11  Blu    2    JKL  PQR
    12  Blu    2    JKL  ZYP
    15  Blu    2    MNO  PQR
    16  Blu    2    MNO  ZYP
    20  Blu    2    PQR  ZYP
```